After upgrade to 24.04 applications delivered as AppImages do not work
I just finished upgrading my Ubuntu Desktop to Noble Numbat 24.04 and after its final reboot, none of the appImage applications that I previously installed will run.  Also I am getting prompted that my "Snap Store" should be updated to 41.3-77, but when you run the update it errors saying "snap-store" has running apps (snap-store),pids: 3969 (which is the application prompting me to update the snap store.

Snap Store cannot update itself (refresh) while running. Quit the application, and then snapd will refresh it. Real Quit, not merely closing the window.

use killall snap-store and after that sudo snap refreshin a terminal, tell us if snaps are refreshed and check your apps try sudo apt install -f all of these commands are for terminal and if you get any unfavorable answer, edit your question with it, do not reply in comment.

This question is similar to: App Center opens as a blank screen in 23.10. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: How to make Balena Etcher appimage work in Ubuntu 24.04?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There are two questions here:
Snap and Snap-store has an answer in comments.
Do sudo apt install libfuse2 and retry running Appimage:s
